# How to permanently store the same text as a "variable" in a text file using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm making a config file with the contents of variables. I made this variable for an example:

```
spawnme=true
```

And here is my Python program:

```
with open('myconfig.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write("spawnme=true")
    
value = open("myconfig.txt").read()
print(value)

if value == "spawnme=true":
    print("YOU SPAWNED ME!")
elif value == "spawnme=false":
    pass
else:
    print("Error reading config!")
```

Let's say the user tweaks the variable from true to false. But it simply just resets to true upon launch of the Python program due to the f.write code. Is there any other way to not reset the variable (false stays false, and true stays true). I apologize if there is something unclear. Thank you!

Comment: Read the file before writing in it ? Then you write you file only if you need to.

Comment: Ok, first of all I didn't think of putting the write first, what a silly mistake, thanks! And about writing the file again, is there any way to make it one-time change? Thanks again!

Comment: I might have found a way of doing that with if else statement, other than that, thank you!

Comment: I don't really get what you want to do, but if your file should be protected from being written a second time if there is a reason for your program to do it event if you don't want to, you could add a kind of boolean flag like `config_saved=False`, and then write your file with a condition like `if not config_saved: ... f.write(...); config_saved=True`.

Comment: Hello again, so I wanted the Python prgram to create a text file first, and then run something using if else. I got it working a couple moments ago. Thanks for the help too!